# Tablet pen that doesnt need a conductive surface/touch the tablet

Tags: tablet

I´m looking for a pen that I can use on any surface (like a table) as a mouse-like input for a tablet, phone or laptop.

Does something like that exist?

Comment: What tablet are you going to use with this stylus? Do you have a budget if a device does exist?

Comment: Many years ago I had a mouse in a pen-like form factor.  Would something like that meet your needs?

Comment: @Cfinley it should work with any bloothooth device

Comment: @Mark that sound interesting, are there ones that you can use with a smartphone?

Comment: No idea.  The one I used was so old it connected to a DB-9 serial port.